# How to specify between identical menu command names when making custom shortcuts.

Tags: macos, mail.app, shortcut, system-settings

I commonly set custom keyboard shortcuts in System Prefs.

I tried setting a shortcut (`command-shift-a`, mirroring `command-shift-j` to move to junk) for Mail app to move messages to archive, since the default shortcut is rather weird (`command-control-a`).

But the menubar command is "Message / Archive", so what I enter in "System Preferences / Keyboard / Shortcuts / App Shortcuts" becomes simply "Archive". Thus it's getting confused with "Mailbox / Go to Favorite Mailbox / Archive".

Is there a way to specify which is which, to avoid the naming collision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on [MacStories](https://www.macstories.net/mac/make-keyboard-shortcuts-for-two-menu-items-with-the-same-name/) and [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/177574/how-to-add-custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-nested-menu-item).

Colliding menubar command names can be specified via their nesting tree, using `->`. Thus the shortcut name in my original question becomes `Message->Archive`.

Comment: I wonder if that's what this paragraph in Help is trying to (and failing to) explain: "In the Menu Title field, type the menu command for which you want to create a shortcut, exactly as the command appears in the app, including the > character (type ->), ellipses (type three periods without spaces or press Option-;), or other punctuation."

Comment: May I ask where you're viewing that Help article?

Comment: Keyboard.prefPane, (?) icon in bottom right, scroll to the bottom and click 'Create keyboard shortcuts for apps' under "See Also". Alternatively, https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25377 :)